# ng-select options are doubled when used with a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement dynamically configurable fields. I will get validation rules ng-required, ng-hidden, ng-disabled etc attributes as json from the server and set them dynamically through a directive.

I have the following directive code. It displays select values doubled JsBin link is http://jsbin.com/jiququtibo/1/edit

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.directive('inputConfig', function( $compile) {
  return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: '=',
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
            console.log("compile 2");
            tElem.removeAttr('data-input-config');
            tElem.removeAttr('input-config');
            tElem.attr('ng-required',true);
            return {
                pre: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs){
                    console.log('pre');
                },
                post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
                    console.log("post");
                    $compile(tElem)(scope);

                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

How can I solve this issue? I should be able to add directive dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution following code is working.You should first clone, remove directive, prepare dom and compile

```
    app.directive('inputConfig', function( $compile) {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            compile:function (t, tAttrs, transclude){
                var tElement = t.clone()  ;
                tElement.removeAttr('input-config');
                tElement.attr('ng-required',true);
                t.attr('ng-required',true);
                return function(scope){
                    // first prepare dom 
                    t.replaceWith(tElement);
                    // than compile
                    $compile(tElement)(scope);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to remove the following line from your **post** function:

```
$compile(tElem)(scope);
```

It's not clear to me why you are compiling here so I'm not sure if there will be any unintended side effects from this.

Comment: If i remove it newly added angularjs ng-required directive wont work. I need to add need to add directives dynamically. see http://jsbin.com/wubomoruli/1/edit that it wont work.